# Как добавить видео на главную страницу сайта без потери скорости загрузки этой страницы на Tilda?

Tags: javascript, tilda

Создаю сайт на cms Tilda первый раз. Внизу главной страницы есть блок с видео - 8 штук. Видео добавлены просто ссылками c ютуба. Этот блок существенно тормозит первичную загрузку сайта. Какие есть способы оптимизировать загрузки? Может как-то можно создать отложенную загрузку этого блока?

Comment: без примера очень тяжело понять как вы выводите видео если это происходит через iframe можно добавить loading="lazy"